# Помогите исправить ошибку index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

задача: нужно найти элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В.
никак не получается сделать этот алгоритм, выдаёт ошибку index was outside the bounds of the array

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEST
{
class Program
{
    static int[] BubbleSort(int[] mas) //сортировка пузырьком, по заданию
    {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < mas.Length; j++)
            {
                if (mas[i] > mas[j])
                {
                    temp = mas[i];
                    mas[i] = mas[j];
                    mas[j] = temp;` }
            }
        }
        return mas;
    }
static void Main(string[] args) //двоичный поиск, по заданию 
    {
        int t1 = Environment.TickCount;
        Random Rnd = new Random();
        int mas_size = 15000, m, lowerBound, upperBound;
        int[] a = new int[mas_size];
        int[] b = new int[mas_size];
        int[] c = new int[mas_size];
        int last_zap = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
        {
            a[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
            b[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
        }
        a = BubbleSort(a);
        b = BubbleSort(b);
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            lowerBound = 0;
            upperBound = mas_size;
            if (last_zap > 0)
            {
                if (c[last_zap - 1] == a[j])
                    continue;
            }

            while (true) //проблемная часть
            {
                m = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
                if (m >= mas_size)
                    break;
                if (a[j] < b[m])
                    upperBound = m - 1;
                else if (a[j] > b[m])
                    lowerBound = m + 1;
                else
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < a.Length; n++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < b.Length; k++)
                            {
                                c[last_zap] = b[m]; //на это ругается
                                last_zap++;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (lowerBound > upperBound || m == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
 int t2 = Environment.TickCount; //установить время работы программы, по заданию
        Console.WriteLine("Продолжительность работы: " + (t2 - t1) / 1000.0);
        if (mas_size <= 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("a[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, a[j]);
                if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("b[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, b[j]);
                if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
            }
            if (last_zap > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\n Элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В:\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < last_zap; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(c[j] + " ");
                }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\n Не соответствуют условию\n");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Ругается на строку `c[last_zap] = b[m];`

Comment: Что за границы массивов? Чем отличается от `mas_size` Пожалуйста, покажите код полностью, а не только цикл.

Comment: добавил полный код

Comment: А что делается внутри длинного for? Зачем там вообще бинарный поиск?

Comment: Зачем двоичный поиск вам нужен? Кого вы ищите?

Comment: в for я пытался сделать условие, что есть значения в массиве А, но их нет в массиве В. Двоичный поиск нужен по условию задания, как я понял мы так сужаем поиск элементов

Comment: @АлександрГусев сузить поиск можно и тем, что просто убрать одинаковые элементы

Comment: ну по задаче нужно использовать двоичный поиск

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last_zap должен быть меньше размера c,   если c[15000] то макс  last_zap =14999 , или размер c должен быть больше, если попробовать

while (last_zap < 15000) //проблемная часть

и кроме "Продолжительность работы: " ничего  не выведет,
у вас int mas_size = 15000

вот тут осталось с массивом `c` разобраться:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] BubbleSort(int[] mas) //сортировка пузырьком, по заданию
        {
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < mas.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (mas[i] > mas[j])
                    {
                        temp = mas[i];
                        mas[i] = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return mas;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) //двоичный поиск, по заданию 
        {
            int t1 = Environment.TickCount;
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            int mas_size = 100, m, lowerBound, upperBound;
            int[] a = new int[mas_size];
            int[] b = new int[mas_size];
            int[] c = new int[mas_size];
            int last_zap = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                a[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
                b[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
            }
            a = BubbleSort(a);
            b = BubbleSort(b);
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                lowerBound = 0;
                upperBound = mas_size;
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                   
                    if (c[last_zap - 1] == a[j])
                        continue;
                }

                while (last_zap < 100) //проблемная часть
                {
                    m = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
                    if (m >= mas_size)
                        break;
                    if (a[j] < b[m])
                        upperBound = m - 1;
                    else if (a[j] > b[m])
                        lowerBound = m + 1;
                    else
                    {
                        for (int n = 0; n < a.Length; n++)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < b.Length; k++)
                            {
                               
                                c[last_zap] = b[m];
                                last_zap++;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (lowerBound > upperBound || m == 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            int t2 = Environment.TickCount; //установить время работы программы, по заданию
            Console.WriteLine("Продолжительность работы: " + (t2 - t1) / 1000.0);
            if (mas_size <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("a[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, a[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("b[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, b[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n Элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В:\n");
                    for (int j = 0; j < last_zap; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(c[j] + " "); 
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Не соответствуют условию\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```